# DateBox Getting the Date

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I am using the DateBox plugin (http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/) for use on a jqm site. I want it to function as a selector for retrieving items from a database. We already have a script written that works on the desktop site that just needs a little modifying. It works by getting the date passed through the URL to select database information. Is it possible to use this plugin, specifically each day item on the calendar as a link? Also, I'm having trouble getting the date. I'm not really following the docs on the website.

Thanks!

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Try mobiscroll.http://mobiscroll.com/
I think it can do most thing.